# fancybox thumbs no way to make it work

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox

[image: invisible thumb]i was using prettyphoto and want to switch to fancybox, my gallery is using isotope for filter and animations, but i dont think this is the issue.
the imagem appears, but no thumb! in dev tools when a picture is selected, there is a `div` called `fancybox-thumbs` but it is invisible! please help

```js
(function ($) {
 //Shortcut for fancyBox object
 var F = $.fancybox;

 //Add helper object
 F.helpers.thumbs = {
  defaults : {
   width    : 50,       // thumbnail width
   height   : 50,       // thumbnail height
   position : 'bottom', // 'top' or 'bottom'
   source   : function ( item ) {  // function to obtain the URL of the thumbnail image
    var href;

    if (item.element) {
     href = $(item.element).find('img').attr('src');
    }

    if (!href && item.type === 'image' && item.href) {
     href = item.href;
    }

    return href;
   }
  },

  wrap  : null,
  list  : null,
  width : 0,

  init: function (opts, obj) {
   var that = this,
    list,
    thumbWidth  = opts.width,
    thumbHeight = opts.height,
    thumbSource = opts.source;

   //Build list structure
   list = '';

   for (var n = 0; n < obj.group.length; n++) {
    list += '<li><a style="width:' + thumbWidth + 'px;height:' + thumbHeight + 'px;" href="javascript:jQuery.fancybox.jumpto(' + n + ');"></a></li>';
   }

   this.wrap = $('<div id="fancybox-thumbs"></div>').addClass(opts.position).appendTo('body');
   this.list = $('<ul>' + list + '</ul>').appendTo(this.wrap);

   //Load each thumbnail
   $.each(obj.group, function (i) {
    var href = thumbSource( obj.group[ i ] );

    if (!href) {
     return;
    }

    $("<img />").load(function () {
     var width  = this.width,
      height = this.height,
      widthRatio, heightRatio, parent;

     if (!that.list || !width || !height) {
      return;
     }

     //Calculate thumbnail width/height and center it
     widthRatio  = width / thumbWidth;
     heightRatio = height / thumbHeight;

     parent = that.list.children().eq(i).find('a');

     if (widthRatio >= 1 && heightRatio >= 1) {
      if (widthRatio > heightRatio) {
       width  = Math.floor(width / heightRatio);
       height = thumbHeight;

      } else {
       width  = thumbWidth;
       height = Math.floor(height / widthRatio);
      }
     }

     $(this).css({
      width  : width,
      height : height,
      top    : Math.floor(thumbHeight / 2 - height / 2),
      left   : Math.floor(thumbWidth / 2 - width / 2)
     });

     parent.width(thumbWidth).height(thumbHeight);

     $(this).hide().appendTo(parent).fadeIn(300);

    }).attr('src', href);
   });

   //Set initial width
   this.width = this.list.children().eq(0).outerWidth(true);

   this.list.width(this.width * (obj.group.length + 1)).css('left', Math.floor($(window).width() * 0.5 - (obj.index * this.width + this.width * 0.5)));
  },

  beforeLoad: function (opts, obj) {
   //Remove self if gallery do not have at least two items
   if (obj.group.length < 2) {
    obj.helpers.thumbs = false;

    return;
   }

   //Increase bottom margin to give space for thumbs
   obj.margin[ opts.position === 'top' ? 0 : 2 ] += ((opts.height) + 15);
  },

  afterShow: function (opts, obj) {
   //Check if exists and create or update list
   if (this.list) {
    this.onUpdate(opts, obj);

   } else {
    this.init(opts, obj);
   }

   //Set active element
   this.list.children().removeClass('active').eq(obj.index).addClass('active');
  },

  //Center list
  onUpdate: function (opts, obj) {
   if (this.list) {
    this.list.stop(true).animate({
     'left': Math.floor($(window).width() * 0.5 - (obj.index * this.width + this.width * 0.5))
    }, 150);
   }
  },

  beforeClose: function () {
   if (this.wrap) {
    this.wrap.remove();
   }

   this.wrap  = null;
   this.list  = null;
   this.width = 0;
  }
 }

}(jQuery));
```

```css
.fancybox-thumbs {
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 8050;
 background: url(../images/icons/icon-magnify.png) center center no-repeat #fff;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 border-radius: 15px;
 opacity: 0.5;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.fancybox-thumbs.bottom {
 bottom: 2px;
}

.fancybox-thumbs.top {
 top: 2px;
}

.fancybox-thumbs ul {
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.fancybox-thumbs ul li {
 float: left;
 padding: 1px;
 opacity: 0.5;
}

.fancybox-thumbs ul li.active {
 opacity: 0.75;
 padding: 0;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.fancybox-thumbs ul li:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}

.fancybox-thumbs ul li a {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 border: 1px solid #222;
 background: #111;
 outline: none;
}

.fancybox-thumbs ul li img {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 border: 0;
 padding: 0;
 max-width: none;
}
#folio {
 background: url(../images/gallery-quote.png) center 80px no-repeat #111;
 padding-top: 100px;
 clear: left;
}
.portfolio_container {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
}
.portfolio_container .portfolio {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 25%;
 height: auto;
}
.portfolio_container .portfolio .media_box figure a img {
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}
.portfolio_container .portfolio .media_box .hover_effect {
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
.gallerySelector {
 background: #222;
 height: 44px;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.gallerySelectorList {
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
.gallerySelectorList li {
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 width: 20%;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0;
}
.gallerySelectorList li:hover {
 background: #83103e;
}
.gallerySelectorList li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 11px 0;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin: 0;
 transition: background-color 0.3s ease, color 0.2s ease;
}
.gallerySelectorList li.current {
 background: #7b133c;
}
.portfolio_container .portfolio {
 width: 20%;
}
.fullwidth {
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
}
#gallery h3 {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.project-title {
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-top: 7px;
}
.project-description {
 color: #868991;
 font-size: 10px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 600;
 margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
.columns .overlay-content.loupe {
 width: 34px;
 height: 34px;
 background: url(../../../templates/images/loupe.png) 0px 0px no-repeat;
 position: absolute;
 top: 22%;
 margin: -17px 0 0 -17px;
 left: 50%;
 z-index: 10;
}
.thumbLink {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}
.thumbImage {
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.thumbImage img {
 transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
.thumbImage .thumbText h3 {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
 transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.thumbImage .thumbText p {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 color: #fff;
 transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.thumbImage .thumbTextWrap {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0 20px;
 opacity: 0;
 background: #7b133c;
 text-align: center;
 transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.ie8 .thumbImage .thumbTextWrap {
 display: none;
}
.thumbImage .thumbTextWrap:before {
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 height: 100%;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin-right: -0.5em;
}
.thumbText {
 text-align: center;
 transform: scale(0);
 transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 90%;
}
.thumbImage:hover img {
 opacity: 0;
 transform: scale(10);
}
.thumbImage:hover .thumbTextWrap {
 opacity: 1;
}
.ie8 .thumbImage:hover .thumbTextWrap {
 display: block;
}
.thumbImage:hover .thumbText {
 transform: scale(1);
}
.thumbLink {
 background: url(../images/icons/icon-magnify.png) center center no-repeat #fff;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 border-radius: 15px;
 opacity: 0.5;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.thumbLink:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}
.portfolioBottom {
 background: #111111;
 height: 44px;
 width: 100%;
 clear: left;
}
.isotope-item {
 z-index: 2;
}
.isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
 pointer-events: none;
 z-index: 1;
}
.isotope, .isotope .isotope-item {
 transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
.isotope {
 transition-property: height, width;
}
.isotope .isotope-item {
 -o-transition-property: top, left, opacity;
 transition-property: transform, opacity;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".fancybox-thumbs").fancybox({
  prevEffect : 'none',
  nextEffect : 'none',
  helpers : {
            thumbs : {
                width  : 50,
                height : 50,
                source: function(current) { 
                return $(current.element).data('thumbnail');
                },
    },
   title : {
    type: 'outside'

   }
  }
 });
});
$("a.grouped_elements").fancybox();
</script>
    

<div id="folio" class="page section">
        
     
        <div class="gallerySelector">
            <ul class="gallerySelectorList">
                <li class='current'><a data-filter="article.portfolio[data-category~='principal']" href="#">Principal</a></li>
                <li><a data-filter="article.portfolio[data-category~='redacao']" href="#">Redação</a></li>
                <li><a data-filter="article.portfolio[data-category~='criacao']" href="#">Redação-Criação</a></li>
                <li><a data-filter="article.portfolio[data-category~='social']" href="#">Social Media</a></li>
                <li><a data-filter="article.portfolio[data-category~='video']" href="#">Audiovisual</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
            
        <section class="portfolio_container">
            
   <article class="portfolio" data-category="principal redacao criacao">
                <section class="thumbImage">
                    <img src="images/gallery/pt-rec1.jpg" alt="" class="fullwidth">
                    <div class="thumbTextWrap">
                        <div class="thumbText">
                            <h3 class="sectionTitle">Gallery Item</h3>
                            <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. </p>
                            <a class="fancybox-thumbs" href="images/gallery/prec1.jpg" rel="fancybox-thumbs" data-thumbnail="images/gallery/pt-rec1.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery-1" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac augue at erat hendrerit dictum."></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </article>

            <article class="portfolio" data-category="principal redacao criacao">
                <section class="thumbImage">
                 <img src="images/gallery/pt-rec2.jpg" alt="" class="fullwidth">
                    <div class="thumbTextWrap">
                        <div class="thumbText">
                            <h3 class="sectionTitle">Gallery Item</h3>
                            <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. </p>
                            <a class="fancybox-thumbs" href="images/gallery/prec2.jpg" rel="fancybox-thumbs" data-thumbnail="images/gallery/pt-rec2.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery-1"><a>title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac augue at erat hendrerit dictum."></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </article> 
            <article class="portfolio" data-category="redacao criacao">
                <section class="thumbImage">
                    <img src="images/gallery/t-rec3.jpg" alt="" class="fullwidth">
                    <div class="thumbTextWrap">
                        <div class="thumbText">
                            <h3 class="sectionTitle">Gallery Item</h3>
                            <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. </p>
                            <a class="fancybox-thumbs" href="images/gallery/rec3.jpg" rel="fancybox-thumbs" data-thumbnail="images/gallery/t-rec3.jpg"data-fancybox-group="gallery-1" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac augue at erat hendrerit dictum."></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to wrap your elements in the  tag with the class bound to fancybox like

```
<a class="fancybox-thumbs" href="image/1_b.jpg" rel="fancybox-thumbs" data-thumbnail="images/1_s.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery-1" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac augue at erat hendrerit dictum.">
    <img src="images/1_s.jpg" alt="" class="fullwidth" />
</a>
```

Then this code will work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fancybox-thumbs").fancybox({
        prevEffect : 'none',
        nextEffect : 'none',
        helpers : {
            thumbs : {
                width : 50,
                height : 50,
                source : function (current) {
                    return $(current.element).data('thumbnail');
                },
            },
            title : {
                type : 'outside'

            }
        }
    });
});
```

You don't need to mess with the original js and css files unless you know what you are doing

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**

**NOTE** : of course, don't forget to include the link to the fancybox thumbs helpers in your page and load them after the fancybox files

Comment: I did all you said, still not able to see the thumbnails!

Comment: I attached a print screen of what happens in dev tools!